# EclipseLink native query and FetchType behaviour

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I'm trying to understand EclipseLink behaviour in case if I use native query. So I have Entity like this:

```
class Entity {

     @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
     @JoinColumn(name="other_entity_id")  
     private OtherEntity otherEntity;

     @Column(name = "name")
     private String name;
     //gets ... sets ...
}
```

and corresponding table looks like:

```
**ENTITY**

INTEGER ID;

VARCHAR NAME;

OTHER_ENTITY_ID;
```

And then I run native query

```
Query query = getEntityManager().runNativeQuery("select * from ENTITY", Entity.class);
query.getResultList()
```

Within `Entity` I have declared `OtherEntity otherEntity` which is annotated with `FetchType.LAZY`, however my query selects (*) - all of the columns, including OTHER_ENTITY_ID. The question is - if I run native query that fetches all columns, will fields annotated with `FetchType.LAZY` populated as if they were `FetchType.EAGER` or not? I've never worked with EclipseLink before and tyring to decide is it worth using it or not so I would really appreciate any help

Thanks, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

My first advice is to turn on EclipseLink's SQL logging, and execute the equivalent JPQL to load what you are looking for and see the SQL EclipseLink generates to accomplish that to get an understanding of what is required to build objects in your native queries based on your current mappings.

Relationships generally loaded with a secondary query using the values read in from the foreign keys, so eager or lazy fetching is not affected by the native query to read in "Entity" - the query requires the other_entity_id value regardless of the fetch type.  When required based on eager/lazy loading, EclipseLink will issue the query required by the mapping.

You can change this though by marking that the relationship is to use [joining](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_joinfetch.htm).  In this case, EclipseLink will expect not only the Entity values to be in the query, but the referenced OtherEntity values as well.